# Is that possible that I use an arbitrary prior distribution that is not conjugate to the likelihood and do mcmc sampling?

Tags: bayesian, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

In Bayesian Statistics, we can use conjugate priors to the likelihood functions, then we can get the posterior distributions which are the same distributions as the prior distributions.

I wonder that if we can use some arbitrary priors that are not conjugate to likelihood functions and run mcmc sampling methods to get the sample from the posterior distributions. Is it allowed to do? Or I can do it but nothing is interpretable? I am not sure if mcmc sampling methods are only allowed for the posterior distribution that are the same type of distribution as the prior distritbuion.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is the exact purpose of MCMC.

Comment: So, the purpose of mcmc sampling methods is to sample from the posterior distribution that does not necessarily come from the conjugate relationship of the prior and the likelhood? I am currently studying it and I need to get the clear idea on this.

Comment: What could be the arbitrary choices for the prior and likelihood?

Comment: For example, a Poisson prior over a set of Gaussian means (let's say you know the means are integers, but you don't know which ones - and you know higher is less likely). Or to be completely arbitrary, a prior drawn from a true RNG - for whatever reason.

Comment: @jkm: If I stretch what you have just said here, you mean that the prior is a Posson prior and the likelihood is a normal likelihood function, and the posterior could be whatever it could be, right?

Comment: Yeah - you have a weird prior you can pick however you wish, but it means your posterior is something crazy as well, so you just simulate the realizations and see what shakes out most of the time.